# Is there a way to change properties of all combination of all products simultaneously

Tags: mysql, prestashop

My father have shop with perfumes and he use presta-shop. He wanted me to change all combinations having '30ml' property and change thier 'atomizer' property from golden to black. Im not in mood to change all 1000 different perfumes. **Is there a way,for instance to download a database write some sql(i know a bit of sql) to search for all '30ml' and change thier atomizer atribute. Or any other way to do it faster.** thanks for all help

My dad wrote e-mail to guy who made his website(althought his question wasn't precize because he dont understand computers) and the guy said that he should do it manually

Comment: Please edit your question to show table schema and some sample data and expected result, and ideally your attempt at the SQL do do it (even if it doesn't work or has syntax errors).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it manually, you can update the data by importing a csv file (Combinations data type). Following the Prestashop guidelines.

Updating this data via SQL is not the most suitable way, you should first find the table, or tables, that contain the data and then create a query to update them. The possibility of errors is very high. Using csv import is faster and easier.